# Can I have a phpbb3 forum in a html5 page

Tags: html, phpbb

I was looking into phpbb3 to create a forum.

I have downloaded and installed the latestet version - 3.0.12

The forum has a XHTML header but I wanted to use it in a html5 page.

Is it possilbe to use phpbb3 in a html 5 page, what's the best way to do this??

Comment: Install a phpBB theme which uses the HTML5 DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in any mad rush to get the forum sorted, phpBB3.1 is currently in its 4th beta test so if you can hold out until the stable release that has an HTML5 doctype as default. Unfortunately there is no official release date but the betas are getting released fairly quickly so hopefully not much longer.